# NetBeans Built file looks different from actual project

Tags: java, netbeans

I created and Clean and Built my NetBeans project. Unfortunately, my jar file looks VERY different from what it is when I run my project from the IDE.
I tried updating java and JDK versions, but those don't help.

> Some differences are: Buttons appear square-shaped(on jar) than rounded edges(on IDE)
>   Panels that were made translucent(IDE) appear light blue(jar)
>   Font sizes differ
>   etc.

Please tell me what must I do to make my built .jar file look exactly what it is on the NetBeans

Comment: May be you should have a look at [How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Comment: Oh, BTW, Swing doesn't handle translucent components very well, especially if you've set the background color using an alpha value.